# My site is not mobile compatible?

Tags: html, css

On my site, I am using bootstrap with the normal container (4.0)

When I make this in to mobile size, it makes weird margins though I'm using percentages?

Code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGwXPN).

Note:

```css
#heading1 {}
#text1 {}
```

Are not used on the site with the issue, so please ignore them.

Comment: post your code here not link of other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say weird margins that is not descriptive enough of the issue. From your example what I can see the text is spilling over. Its the text in the jumbotron, The font size is 4.5rem, if you reduce this in the mobile view it will not bleed past the container.

The class that I am referring to that adds the font size is:

```
.display-3 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
```